# How to check if a MySQL database backup is stale

Tags: mysql, rds

I am working on an application that we need disaster recovery plans. We currently use RDS to host the db and have 2 hourly backups running (we do not use Aurora but have plans to upgrade in future).

If the database somehow got deleted we want to make sure the backup we will be recovering from is current and therefore need some way of telling that.

One way is to save a heartbeat in the db at certain intervals then i can check that against what is expected.

I was wondering if anyone may have any other ways of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this MySQL database is connected to your web application, you could have a server side thread in your application which periodically does a heartbeat which writes a record to the database.  You may create a special heartbeat table, which will store the heartbeats.  Then, you can easily examine any backup and know roughly the last time the database were "alive."

I am not an expert in AWS, and there may be another way of doing this which is easier than what I described above.e